# How to start emacsclient on emacs 27, ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, daemon, emacsclient

What is the equivalent of `emacsclient -a ''` with emacs 27 on Ubuntu 18? I now get

```
$ emacsclient -a ''
emacsclient: file name or argument required
Try 'emacsclient --help' for more information
```

Without the fallback of starting an emacs daemon and then connecting again as had worked previously. This had worked on ubuntu 16.04 as well, so I assume it has something to do with Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass either `-t` or `-n`. If you want a GUI window: `emacsclient -nc -a ''`.  If you want it to run in the terminal either `emacsclient -t -a ''` or `emacsclient -nw -a ''` will do what you want.